# Can you match Google Analytics and DCM/DBM impressions on Big Query at user-level?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, double-click-advertising

I use both the Analytics 360 integration for Big Query and DCM/DBM Big Query Transfer for programmatic advertising.

In the ga_sessions table, GA assigns a "fullvisitorid", a 18-character all-numerical value, to each session.

In the table that tracks the impressions of my DCM/DCM campaigns, a 28-alphanumerical value ("user_id") is assigned to users who served impressions.

I'm interested in joining those two tables at FullVisitorId/User_Id to analyse the post-landing behaviour of users who were in specific campaigns. This would, for example, allow me to calculate conversions without the need of Floodlights.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: what exactly is the question. How to do a join in SQL?

Comment: @GrahamPolley - VisitorId and User_id are different between themselves. One is 18-character numerical and the other is 28-character alphanumerical. I was wondering if there a solution for this - either a way to de-hash, pass over one of them as a custom value or a Google solution/integration I'm not aware of.

Comment: Hashing is one way. You can't "de-hash". In order to join (in any DB) you need a common key. It doesn't sound like you have one though. Have you tried joining on the hashed id, and seeing what the results are?